# Repair Mysql table structure from existing frm file

Tags: mysql

i have moved my mysql database from another computer, but when i moved to the other some table seems doesn't exist, when i check to mysql data folder, the  MYI and MYD from  table is gone, just FRM left, how do i create the same table structure from existing FRM ? never mind if the data is gone. i just need the structure, so how i could do that ? by the way, i am using windows, i have try with this command but it seem doesn't work

```
mysql> repair TABLE m_tarif2012 USE_FRM;
+-----------------------+--------+----------+------------------+
| Table                 | Op     | Msg_type | Msg_text         |
+-----------------------+--------+----------+------------------+
| rsud_2012.m_tarif2012 | repair | Warning  | Can't open table |
| rsud_2012.m_tarif2012 | repair | status   | Operation failed |
+-----------------------+--------+----------+------------------+
2 rows in set (0.01 sec)
```

Answer (score 2):

I have never done it, but [this blog post](http://www.mysqlperformanceblog.com/2008/12/17/recovering-create-table-statement-from-frm-file/) might be useful. You should be able to just create the .MYI and .MYD files (with the correct mysql file permissions) to recover the table structure. But as you said, you won't have the data recovered.

Answer (score 1):

I just answered a question like this 8 days ago

[How can extract the table schema from just the .frm file?](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/44314/how-can-extract-the-table-schema-from-just-the-frm-file/44316#44316)

There is a [Windows Utility](http://dev.mysql.com/downloads/tools/utilities/) to Regenerate the `CREATE TABLE` SQL to stdout

I tried it out on `mysql.user`'s .frm to see what it makes. It worked that day.

Give it a Try !!!

Comment: Then why answer the question, instead of voting to close the question as a duplicate?