# How can extract the table schema from just the .frm file?

Tags: mysql, innodb, schema, recovery

I have extracted the data directory of mysql from a backup and need to get the schema from an old table, however it's a backup from a different machine.

I have read a fair number of tutorials today on how to do this, but each time it seems to fail or I end up having to reinstall mysql because mysql hangs or crashes. I have tried the following:

- Create a different database
- Create table with same name in that database
- Replace file
- Stop/Start engine
- Recover from the `.frm` file

I have tried in various orders and combinations.

Is there any external tool that can extract the schema from the `.frm` file? I can see the column names if I open up the file. I had a look but I can't seem to find anything that will enable me to do this.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 5):

I have answered questions like this before

- `Dec 21, 2011` : [Table compression in InnoDB?](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/9500/table-compression-in-innodb/9555#9555)
- `Feb 03, 2012` : [How to recover MySQL table structure from FRM files](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/12223/how-to-recover-mysql-table-structure-from-frm-files/12229#12229)
- `Apr 23, 2012` : [restore table from .frm and .ibd file?](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/16875/mysql-how-to-restore-table-stored-in-a-frm-and-a-ibd-file/16911#16911)

I have referred to a [blog from Chris Calendar](http://www.chriscalender.com/?tag=innodb-error-tablespace-id-in-file) on connecting `.ibd` files back to the data dictionary.

If you do not have the `.ibd` along with `.frm`, chances are MySQL was running with [innodb_file_per_table](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/innodb-parameters.html#sysvar_innodb_file_per_table) off. Please refer to the `Feb 03, 2012` post on that. If this is Linux, make sure you run

```
cd /var/lib/mysql
chown -R mysql:mysql *
```

before starting mysql.

Give it a Try !!!

## SUPPLEMENTARY INFO

- [Percona's mysqlperformanceblog.com has information on this from over 4 years ago](http://www.mysqlperformanceblog.com/2008/12/17/recovering-create-table-statement-from-frm-file/)
- [MySQL Utility Team has the tool mysqlfrm](http://drcharlesbell.blogspot.com/2013/04/mysql-utilities-new-frm-reader-utility.html).

At the bottom of that last blog it says:

> Ok, I'm Hooked! Where Can I Get It?
>
> The .frm reader utility is part of the new release-1.3.0 Alpha
>   available as a separate download at
>   http://dev.mysql.com/downloads/tools/utilities/. Simply choose the
>   platform repository or source repository and download it.
>
> We welcome your comments and hope that this utility will help expand
>   your diagnosis and recovery toolkit.

## UPDATE 2013-06-11 14:05 EDT

I have good news. I installed the Windows version of the MySQL Utilities. I tested the mysqlfrm program from the command line. I tested getting the `.frm` info from the user.frm in the mysql schema. Here is what I got:

```
C:\MySQL_5.6.10\data\mysql>mysqlfrm --server=root:rootpassword@localhost mysql:user.frm --port=3307
# Source on localhost: ... connected.
# Starting the spawned server on port 3307 ... done.
# Reading .frm files
#
# Reading the user.frm file.
#
# CREATE statement for user.frm:
#

CREATE TABLE `mysql`.`user` (
  `Host` char(60) COLLATE utf8_bin NOT NULL DEFAULT '',
  `User` char(16) COLLATE utf8_bin NOT NULL DEFAULT '',
  `Password` char(41) CHARACTER SET latin1 COLLATE latin1_bin NOT NULL DEFAULT '',
  `Select_priv` enum('N','Y') CHARACTER SET utf8 NOT NULL DEFAULT 'N',
  `Insert_priv` enum('N','Y') CHARACTER SET utf8 NOT NULL DEFAULT 'N',
  `Update_priv` enum('N','Y') CHARACTER SET utf8 NOT NULL DEFAULT 'N',
  `Delete_priv` enum('N','Y') CHARACTER SET utf8 NOT NULL DEFAULT 'N',
  `Create_priv` enum('N','Y') CHARACTER SET utf8 NOT NULL DEFAULT 'N',
  `Drop_priv` enum('N','Y') CHARACTER SET utf8 NOT NULL DEFAULT 'N',
  `Reload_priv` enum('N','Y') CHARACTER SET utf8 NOT NULL DEFAULT 'N',
  `Shutdown_priv` enum('N','Y') CHARACTER SET utf8 NOT NULL DEFAULT 'N',
  `Process_priv` enum('N','Y') CHARACTER SET utf8 NOT NULL DEFAULT 'N',
  `File_priv` enum('N','Y') CHARACTER SET utf8 NOT NULL DEFAULT 'N',
  `Grant_priv` enum('N','Y') CHARACTER SET utf8 NOT NULL DEFAULT 'N',
  `References_priv` enum('N','Y') CHARACTER SET utf8 NOT NULL DEFAULT 'N',
  `Index_priv` enum('N','Y') CHARACTER SET utf8 NOT NULL DEFAULT 'N',
  `Alter_priv` enum('N','Y') CHARACTER SET utf8 NOT NULL DEFAULT 'N',
  `Show_db_priv` enum('N','Y') CHARACTER SET utf8 NOT NULL DEFAULT 'N',
  `Super_priv` enum('N','Y') CHARACTER SET utf8 NOT NULL DEFAULT 'N',
  `Create_tmp_table_priv` enum('N','Y') CHARACTER SET utf8 NOT NULL DEFAULT 'N',
  `Lock_tables_priv` enum('N','Y') CHARACTER SET utf8 NOT NULL DEFAULT 'N',
  `Execute_priv` enum('N','Y') CHARACTER SET utf8 NOT NULL DEFAULT 'N',
  `Repl_slave_priv` enum('N','Y') CHARACTER SET utf8 NOT NULL DEFAULT 'N',
  `Repl_client_priv` enum('N','Y') CHARACTER SET utf8 NOT NULL DEFAULT 'N',
  `Create_view_priv` enum('N','Y') CHARACTER SET utf8 NOT NULL DEFAULT 'N',
  `Show_view_priv` enum('N','Y') CHARACTER SET utf8 NOT NULL DEFAULT 'N',
  `Create_routine_priv` enum('N','Y') CHARACTER SET utf8 NOT NULL DEFAULT 'N',
  `Alter_routine_priv` enum('N','Y') CHARACTER SET utf8 NOT NULL DEFAULT 'N',
  `Create_user_priv` enum('N','Y') CHARACTER SET utf8 NOT NULL DEFAULT 'N',
  `Event_priv` enum('N','Y') CHARACTER SET utf8 NOT NULL DEFAULT 'N',
  `Trigger_priv` enum('N','Y') CHARACTER SET utf8 NOT NULL DEFAULT 'N',
  `Create_tablespace_priv` enum('N','Y') CHARACTER SET utf8 NOT NULL DEFAULT 'N',
  `ssl_type` enum('','ANY','X509','SPECIFIED') CHARACTER SET utf8 NOT NULL DEFAULT '',
  `ssl_cipher` blob NOT NULL,
  `x509_issuer` blob NOT NULL,
  `x509_subject` blob NOT NULL,
  `max_questions` int(11) unsigned NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
  `max_updates` int(11) unsigned NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
  `max_connections` int(11) unsigned NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
  `max_user_connections` int(11) unsigned NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
  `plugin` char(64) COLLATE utf8_bin DEFAULT '',
  `authentication_string` text COLLATE utf8_bin,
  `password_expired` enum('N','Y') CHARACTER SET utf8 NOT NULL DEFAULT 'N',
  PRIMARY KEY (`Host`,`User`)
) ENGINE=MyISAM DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8 COLLATE=utf8_bin COMMENT='Users and global privileges'

#...done.

C:\MySQL_5.6.10\data\mysql>
```

It really works. The database is running on my desktop computer using port 3306. I had to give 3307 as a port to run a spawned process.

I could move the `.frm` from a Linux box to the Windows machine and do the same.

Give it a Try !!!