# Restoring a database with just .idb and .frm files

Tags: restore, files

I've never attempted something like this before. We had a WAMP installation with WordPress running on my wife's PC, and the Aestan tray menu failed. I figured we need to uninstall and re-install WAMP, which left the data files in .ibd and .frm files along with the core WordPress installation. I'm trying to bring them back to life again to be used. The WAMP people recommended I find a way to restore the database files.

I read a post here ([Recover MySQL database from data folder without ibdata1 from ibd files](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/57120/recover-mysql-database-from-data-folder-without-ibdata1-from-ibd-files/142836?noredirect=1#comment270943_142836)) regarding someone who had the same set of "leftover" files, and was given some advice regarding how to restore using some MySQL utilties. They said, "you can download a MySQL utility that can generate the SQL needed to create the table." I went to Oracle and downloaded the Windows version of their utilities, but there are around 24 .exe files in there! I have no idea which one to use. I was expecting a single app in there, not a collection.

I'm not afraid to try this, but it's not clear which utility(ies) I should use. I'm trusting that the instructions could make sense once I'm actually attempting it. I've been in PHPAdmin a few times so I do know how to make some edits, but doing a restore like this with .ibd and .frm files is new territory for me.

Details: My WAMP installation was using MySQL 5.6.12, and the new WAMP installation uses 5.6.17. The WAMP people said if I restore the database in the 5.6.12 then I'll be able to choose the 5.6.12 setup from the Aestan tray menu. I have made backup copies of the 5.6.12 database files. So I'm ready to attempt this, but would appreciate a little advice from any of you.

Comment: Take a look [here](https://twindb.com) also.

Comment: Check [here](http://dba.stackexchange.com/a/16911/34007).

Comment: I've had some conversation with Alexandr on that first link. He mentioned I could restore with just the ibdata1 files and the files I have. Problem is: the WAMP uninstall left just the .frm and .ibd files, with no ibdata1 file in the main MySQL 5.6.12 folder. It would appear my only hope is if I can get a ibdata1 file recreated. Why the WAMP people allowed an uninstall to leave the parts it did without the other parts to make it work, I'm not understanding.

Comment: Also, on the second link, Roland says "Run the SQL to create the InnoDB table". What SQL utility do I run to do that and what would the command be to create that? He doesn't elaborate, and his post requires a 50 reputation to comment.