# Need proper mysqlfrm command to get into ibdata file to restore a database

Tags: mysql

I'm attempting to restore a database made up of only .ibd and .frm files. Why I'm doing this: An uninstall of my WAMP installation left only .ibd and .frm files, and was using MySQL 5.6.12. A reinstall of WAMP has MySQL 5.6.17. The WAMP people said if I restore the database in the 5.6.12 then I'll be able to choose the 5.6.12 setup from the Aestan tray menu.

I'm trying to use mysqlfrm to to do this but my command execution appears to be off.

My WAMP database is located at `C:\wamp\bin\mysql\mysql5.6.12\data\wordpress.`

Here is the path I tried: `C:\wamp\bin\mysql\mysql5.6.12\data\wordpress>c:\utilities\mysqlfrm --server=root:rootpassword@localhost --port=3307`.

I got this set of responses: `WARNING: Using a password on the command line interface can be insecure. Usage: mysqlfrm --server[user[:<pass>]@host[:<port>][:<socket>]:<login-path>[:<port>][:<socket>]‌​] [path\tbl1.frm:db:tbl.frm]`

and mysqlfrm: error: `Nothing to do. You must specify a list of paths or files to read. See --help for more information and examples.`

Someone shared that according to the error message, I am using the command line arguments incorrectly and that "The messages even shows you the *correct* options".

I'm basing my command on another post's example here. So I'm not understanding how `socket` would be involved. Could someone post what my command should look like? I'm pretty new at this so any advice would be greatly appreciated. Thanks.

By the way, my port number is a guess based on what someone else did. I could use some help if my port number should be different. I've done a LOT of reading here on how to do this and have been at it for several weeks. Reference: [Restoring a database with just .idb and .frm files](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/142920/restoring-a-database-with-just-idb-and-frm-files) (That's my question earlier in the process. I'm slowly working my way toward a solution. Just trying to get answers to get this to work. Each time I ask I'm getting clues, but there's still missing info that I find I don't have each step I take.)

Comment: It's not a duplicate. That's my question earlier in the process. I'm slowly working my way toward a solution. Just trying to get answers to get this to work. Each time I ask I'm getting clues, but there's still missing info that I find I don't have each step I take.