# Trying to recover a database with just .ibd and .frm files, but no idbata1 file

Tags: mysql, ibdata

Trying to restore a WAMP database with just .frm and .ibd files. The uninstall of WAMP left .ibd and .frm files, but no ibdata1 file. I have read several posts here to figure out the process for doing this.

I read this post:  [Recover MySQL database from data folder without ibdata1 from ibd files](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/57120/recover-mysql-database-from-data-folder-without-ibdata1-from-ibd-files/142836?noredirect=1#comment270943_142836) . I also got advice to bring in a ibdata1 file in from a fresh WAMP MySQL installation . (My old WAMP was a 5.6.12, this new one installed 5.6.17). I ran the .frm files through a utility at TwinDB: https://recovery.twindb.com/ which I understand helps get the schema restored.

The instructions are this: to run commands through a MySQL utility after copying .ibd files to the data level folder, then moving the .ibd files back to the database level. I assume the .frm files that were run through TwinDB's utility are to replace the existing .frm files in my database folder. There are eleven .ibd files to run through this process.

My hope when I'm done is that my 5.6.12 installation will be legitimate, and that WAMP's tray menu will recognize my 5.6.12 installation once again. I have several years of archived posts there that I want to re-use again online.

I downloaded the MySQL Utilities (1.5.6) and installed them. I've read here that I should be using mysql.exe. But that file is not in the folder that was installed. I'm stuck. There are 24 .exe files in that folder. The READ ME file gives me no instructions. Which utility am I supposed to use if mysql.exe is not in there? Why didn't the installation of the Utilities create an app that opens up all these tools?

My database is located at C:\wamp\bin\mysql\mysql5.6.12\data\wordpress. I know I need that path to log in. What is my command to log into this server path so I can run my commands and restore these connections between my eleven .ibd files?
My database user is root. There is no password since this is an internal server.

I've read that I need to log in to mysql so I can run these commands to put the database info in the directory with the ibdata file so that everything can "connect" again. The .ibd files have all the data for the internal WordPress site. Their files sizes are clearly indicative that all the data is there.

Answer (score 0):

Answer copied from [this site](https://bmehla.wordpress.com/2011/04/30/run-mysql-command-line-with-wamp/), but abridged and adjusted so the path matches your directory structure.

1. Run cmd command
2. Type **C:**  and hit enter
3. C:>**cd wamp\bin\mysql\mysql5.6.12\bin**
4. C:\wamp\bin\mysql\mysql5.6.12\bin>**mysql.exe -u root**