# Table is dropped but ibd file still exists

Tags: mysql, innodb

I was dropping some unwanted tables I have in the MySQL. When I run a drop table, its showing table doesnot exists. But when a check in the data directory, the .ibd file exists and its almost 1GB. How can i free that space/drop table now ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can go to the OS and drop the file because the data dictionary in the system tablespace (ibdata1) does not know of the `.ibd` file's existence any more.

I wrote a post 2 months ago about deleting temporary `.ibd` files : [temp table (#sql-7a87_230c32.ibd along with its .frm) still exists on slave](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/67866/temp-table-sql-7a87-230c32-ibd-along-with-its-frm-still-exists-on-slave/67871#67871). It applies in your case as well.

## Give it a Try !!!